# text shadow not display correctly in ie css

Tags: html, css

I have applied text shadow for my heading using the following css.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, span {

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999 !important; 


filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=#999999,offX=1,offY=1);
}

h1{

 filter: Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Direction=130, Strength=1);}
```

Html:

`<h1>Contact Us</h1>`

It looks fine in firefox but looks odd in ie 8 and ie 9. Please refer the below images.

Firefox:

[image]

IE 8:

[image]

How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter and change the strength and direction as needed.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=60, Color='#999999');
```

Comment: If I apply this css the shadow works well, but the smoothness of font is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, span {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999 !important; 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=#999999,offX=1,offY=1);
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

h1{
     filter: Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Direction=130, Strength=1);
}
```

Comment: If I apply background color it looks like image 3 in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer. Thanks to this post http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/04/14/css3-text-shadow-can-it-be-done-in-ie-without-javascript/

HTML:

```
<h1>
<span>Contact Us</span>
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, span {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999 !important; 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=#999999,offX=1,offY=1);
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

h1{
    zoom: 1;
    background-color: white;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color=white)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=1, OffY=1, Color=#eeeeee);
    font-size:20px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ9rs/3/)